# QtGstreamer camerabin2 usage

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

I'm working on `olimex a13` board with just `eglfs` i.e, no windowing system. Because of this `Qt Multimedia` stuff video and camera aren't working as `Qt` uses `Gstreamer` which in turn needs `X`. So I'm using `QtGstreamer` library which is [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/index.html).

I've followed the [examples](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/examples_2qmlplayer_2main_8cpp-example.html) and created a media player which is working as expected. Now, I want to do a camera and using `camerabin2` which is from bad [plugins](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-camerabin2.html).

This is my code:

```
//init QGst
QGst::init(&argc, &argv);
//create video surface
QGst::Quick::VideoSurface* videoSurface = new QGst::Quick::VideoSurface(&engine);

CameraPlayer player;
player.setVideoSink(videoSurface->videoSink());
```

//cameraplayer.cpp

```
void open() 
{
    if (!m_pipeline) {
        m_pipeline = QGst::ElementFactory::make("camerabin").dynamicCast<QGst::Pipeline>();
        if (m_pipeline) {
            m_pipeline->setProperty("video-sink", m_videoSink);
            //watch the bus for messages
            QGst::BusPtr bus = m_pipeline->bus();
            bus->addSignalWatch();
            QGlib::connect(bus, "message", this, &CameraPlayer::onBusMessage);
            //QGlib::connect(bus, "image-done", this, &CameraPlayer::onImageDone);
        } else {
            qCritical() << "Failed to create the pipeline";
        }
    }
}
//-----------------------------------
void CameraPlayer::setVideoSink(const QGst::ElementPtr & sink)
{
    m_videoSink = sink;
}

//-----------------------------------
void CameraPlayer::start()
{
    m_pipeline->setState(QGst::StateReady);
    m_pipeline->setState(QGst::StatePlaying);
}
```

I then call `cameraPlayer.start()` which isn't working i.e, no video. Am I missing something here? Has anyone used `QtGstreamer` to stream webcam? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am having the same issue i.e. no video displays on my videosink.

Comment: @Luca, please check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised some plugins (multifilesink) were missing. Started my `Qt` application with `--gst-debug-level=4` argument and `gstreamer` then reported about missing plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try this tonight and see if it solves my problem!